# How to execute a VSTS query using WIQL from C# when the query contains "\"

Tags: c#, azure-devops, wiql

I have a VSTS item that has in the Description field a stack trace, so it has "\" characters. See below the WIQL query.

In my C# app, I executed this query both through Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.Client and through REST API and the ticket is not found.

Is there a way to execute this query and find the ticket?

```
@"Select [Id]
From WorkItems
Where [Work Item Type] = 'Alert'
And [System.TeamProject] = 'Fabrikam'
And [System.Title] = 'title 1'
And [System.Description] Contains 'a\b'
Order By [State] Asc, [Changed Date] Desc"
```

Comment: Try `CONTAINS WORDS 'a\b'`

Comment: CONTAINS WORDS 'a\b' doesn't work either

Comment: Ok, try this: `a\\b`